# Data not edited using PUT in nodejs express

Tags: node.js, express

I'm new on Node.js and I.m facing a problem. I want to edit a data by username, but nothing happen (the data still the same, no error) when I try it using postman. Please take a look on my code:

```js
//Edit User
app.put("/user/:username", (req, res) => {
    userData = userData.filter( user => {
        if (user.username === req.params.username) {
            const newUser = {
                name: req.body.name ,
                email: req.body.email ,
                username: req.body.username,
                password: req.body.password,
                role: req.body.role,
            }
            userData.push(newUser)
        }
        return res.json(userData)
    })
})
```

And screenshot on my postman:
[image]

Can someone help me? Thanks before!

Comment: Have you tried console.log inside the if to check if the if is beeing executed?

Comment: what is `userData`? and why are you trying to modify data in what appears to be some sort of find operations (filter).

Comment: @ChristianFritz `userData` is an array of object where I store the data. Um, honestly that's what I think how to update the data? Because I've tried without the filter and the data still not updated. And when I change it to `map` operations, it add new data, not updating it.

Answer (score 2):

You are adding new items to the `userData` over and over again using the `.push()`. What you want is to update the **existing** array item:

```js
if (user.username === req.params.username) {
  user.name = req.body.email;
  ...
  user.role = req.body.role;
}
```

Also, your route have bugs. If such `username` is not found you might want to return HTTP 404. Here is how I would write the same REST endpoint:

```js
//Edit User
app.put("/user/:username", (req, res) => {
    const user = userData.find(u => u.username === req.param.username);
    if (!user) return res.sendStatus(404); // assuming you are using Express.js

    const { name, email, username, password, role } = req.body;
    Object.assign(user, { name, email, username, password, role });

    res.json(userData);
})
```